# Mixed Simplified-Traditional script on Twins' album cover - why?

Tags: traditional-vs-simplified

On the album art for Twins' first album (我們的紀念冊), 紀 and 冊 are written as simplified characters. What's the reason for this (aside from artistic ones), and would people notice this?

Here's the album art in question:
[image: 我們的紀念冊 by Twins]

EDIT: Found another mixed script album art (雙生兒). This does not look like sloppy font to me...

[image: 雙生兒 by Twins]

Comment: This looks more like simplified with a traditional character rather than traditional with two simplified characters.

Comment: But Twins are a HK band and this album is Cantopop though, so I suppose it's traditional.

Comment: This can be attributed to a mistake. I know people who learn and use simplified and traditional characters haphazardly, and that's how they write Chinese - a random mix of simplified and traditional characters, using whichever character that comes to mind first.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of "Simplified" characters existed as short-hand forms of Chinese characters long before the "simplification" of the written language in the PRC. Conversely, the PRC hasn't given up "traditional" characters completely. I wouldn't be surprised to see some mixing here and there.

Comment: But why in this case though? I know that many "simplified" characters are taken from shorthand/variant forms that are common in use in all regions, but this is print...

Comment: Artistic effect, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the two words that written in simplified Chinese because maybe this album is for simplified Chinese users. Also, the two words "紀" and "冊", are difficult for simplified Chinese users to understand the meaning. I'm not sure either, sorry. But it's so weird that contain both traditional and simplified Chinese characters. Idk.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's just a mistake of staff here. Maybe they used a wrong glyph but didn't find that.
As @K Man said, sometimes, people can't distinguish Simplified and Traditional exactly.